# When is it appropriate to use \rightarrow or \leftrightarrow

Tags: article-writing

When writing papers on maths, when is it appropriate to use \rightarrow or \leftrightarrow, and when should one refrain from using them. For example, would this [image]

be appropriate use of \leftrightarrow.

EDIT: 
What about this
[image]
Credit to Servaes, Peter Woolfitt and Michael, not trying to steal or anything, just using as an example. Should I make some arrows, or should I just line them up like in the picture.

Comment: No, you want just $=$ in this case.

Comment: And when transforming equations? Do you make arrows in all cases?

Comment: Yes. $\Leftrightarrow$ simply means "if and only if".

Comment: In most cases, write it out in words, do not use $\Longrightarrow$.

Answer (score 1):

Arrows such as $\iff$ and $\implies$ mean "if and only if" and "implies" and are used to show connection between **statements**. In the case of what you wrote you simply need equalities "$=$".

And arrows such as $\rightarrow$ have even different meanings. This one I see most often used to specify a domain and codomain of a function, like this: $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$. But it probably has other uses too.

Comment: $\to$ also means "syntactically implies" in logic. For example, $\vdash p \to (q \to p)$.

Comment: Yes, in logic, some authors distinguish between single arrows and double arrows.  e.g. one might refer to the material conditional--which is what the example you gave, @PatrickStevens, probably means--and the other might mean something stronger, such as logical implication.  In general, I think you have to know the context.  Often, a careful author will define his/her arrows.   In other cases, you can just figure it out if you understand the material well enough.